# lseek command (Disk Allocation)

Tags: allocation, lseek

"The lseek command repositions the offset of the descriptor fildes to the argument offset according to the directive whence and is mainly used in file system implementation for Indexed Disk Allocation"

I was reading my professor's powerpoint and came upon this statement.  What I don't understand is how the lseek command ties in to indexed disk allocation compared to Linked and contiguous.  Could someone explain why it says indexed disk allocation is easier to implement than Contiguous or Linked?

From what I read from another source: "The lseek() command will degrade into O(N) time because we will need to scan the file allocation table sequentially to access file data."

Wouldn't this relate to contiguous disk allocation more because it blocks allocated data sequentially.

Comment: lseek with a large offset followed by a write of a single byte can be used (on some disks/file system implementations) to artificially increase the file's size, thus allocating / reserving space on the disk.

Comment: But would that mean index disk allocation would be better?  Why index over linked or contiguous?